# Centering date labels on Google Charts hAxis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

If I use date values for the hAxis of a Google Charts column chart, the labels appear below the bar group divider (see pic below). This does not happen if I use strings.
[image: Google Chart Issue]
Has anyone figured out how to make the date label to appear centered below each bar group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide your own `ticks` for the `hAxis` option...

use the dates from the data for each tick / label...

```
var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
  ticks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
}
```

then assign in the options...

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: ticks
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y0');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y1');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 07, 08), 200, 210],
    [new Date(2017, 07, 15), 190, 220],
    [new Date(2017, 07, 22), 205, 200]
  ]);

    var ticks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      ticks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
    }

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 24,
      height: '100%',
      left: 48,
      right: 96,
      top: 24,
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: ticks
    },
    height: '100%',
    title: 'Title',
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: It helped indeed, thanks @whitehat! The major difference now is that the tick is between the bars, so the hAxis labels are centered around the ticks and, of course, underneath the bars. Good enough for what I need! Cheers!